# How to call remote object in controller(MVC) c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As title, I have a class Services implement interface IServices. And when create a web application C#(using mvc) i want to using IServices but i don't know how to make Controller understand IServices is definitive by Services.
 Can anyone help me?

---

Any help really appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You need to register your IService implementation in your DI container

Comment: I've posted you a simple example which should get you moving. For future reference, always make an attempt and post some code to avoid getting down voted.

Comment: Wheels73 gave you the answer you seek. I recommend reading Pro ASP MVC 5. this book explain basic asp coding and should give you basic foundation including using interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a number of approaches to this dependent upon your solution set up. If you implement something like the below, then is should give you a degree of flexibility.

```
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        private IService _myService;

        public TestController (IServices myService)
        {
            _myService = service;
        }

        public TestController() : this (new ServiceImplementation)
        {

        }
    }
```

In the controller we provide a mechanism for constructor dependency injection where a concrete implementation of the interface is provided usually via a DI container or in some cases a custom controller factory. We then also allow the controller to control the default instantiation of the implementation it needs itself if no injection is provided. We achieve this by having a parameter less constructor that passes a concrete implementation to the DI constructor.

NOTE: The above is just one approach and is open to interpretation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why do we need ```We then also allow the controller to control the default instantiation of the implementation it needs itself if no injection is provided``` here?

Comment: @tym32167 - We don't need... it's just an approach I've seen and used in the past. That could be removed and then just allow the controller to instance the services when required in the constructor or whatever you prefer.

Comment: ok, got it, thx.